# How do I create a custom class from a class that already exists? (Existing class does not support NSCoding)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, subclassing, nscoding

What I'm trying to do is convert an `EKEvent` into `NSData`, and then convert it back into an `EKEvent`.

I looked around and noticed that in order to use `NSKeyedArchiver`, the class must conform to the `NSCoding` protocol. I also found that if I was creating a custom class, I could make it conform to the `NSCoding` protocol by implementing `encodeWithCoder:` on such a custom class.

Essentially, I assume that in order to convert my `EKEvent` to `NSData` and back, I will need to create a custom class (let us call it `CustomEvent`) I need to do the following:

```
EKEvent --> CustomEvent --> NSData --> CustomEvent --> EKEvent
```

Can I get any help on learning how to create a custom class which DUPLICATES an existing class with the exception that I implement `encodeWithCoder:` to make it conform to `NSCoding`?

I'm looking at EKEvent.h, and I know that it involves other classes which I must also duplicate (because they too don't conform to `NSCoding`). Can anyone send me a tutorial link or help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing appears to be a [subclass](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-SW1).

However, in Objective-C, you have the simpler option of defining a [category on an existing class](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) to add the functionality you want.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. So I've created the .m and .h, But I still don't know how I should handle the following:

EKEvent has a few objects, such as:
    NSDate             *_dateStamp;

So when I define - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder, from Apple Documentation (regarding custom subclasses) I see that I should put:
    [coder encodeObject:dateStamp forKey:@"dateStamp"];

of course, XCode complains that the "dateStamp" object does not exist (because it is not declared in the Category). Do I just re-declare? Would there be a problem with that (I assume there would)?

Comment: The name of the field is `_dateStamp`, not `dateStamp`, and as long as you're importing the header, it should be visible. However, I would be careful not to run afoul of implementation details that might change in the future.